# requestClientCertificate error on browser

Tags: ssl, dart

I try to request a SSL certificate, but it doesn't work...

When I do this:

```dart
void main() {
  SecureSocket.initialize(
    database: './bin/security',
    password: 'dartdart'
  );

  HttpServer.bindSecure('127.0.0.1', 8443, certificateName: 'Dart').then
  ((server) => server.listen((req) {
    req.response.write('hello');
    req.response.close();
  }));
}
```

It's ok, I get a warning message about the certificate, I proceed anyway, then I get 'hello'.

When I add the requestClientCertificate flag in bindSecure, the browser ask me to choose a certificate from a list, I choose one, I get on the browser `Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` but no error from the server side.

I miss something ?

I'm on mac os marverick.

Comment: Can you try with another browser for example Firefox and add the error message you get there (if any).

Comment: No error message, and didn't ask for a certificate, then req.certificate is null.

Comment: It's because it's a self signed ?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208618/how-to-fix-node-js-https-server-ssl-error help?  It's in a different programming language but it might by applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the certificate into Chrome since you said it's self-signed.

```
chrome://settings
Show advanced settings...
HTTPS/SSL -> Manage certificates...
Import... (follow the wizard)
```

Comment: I'm on OS X, the certificates manager is keychain. It's by him that I did the certificate.