# How to fix Node.js HTTPS Server "SSL Error"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, express, https

I'm trying to use `express` in conjunction with a node.js `https` server, but I'm getting a warning when I connect.

[image: The site's security certificate is not trusted!]

---

My code is:

```js
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
    , https = require('https')
    , fs = require('fs')
    , express = require('express')
    , app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var options = {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false,
    key: fs.readFileSync('private/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('private/cert.pem')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(8888);

var MainServer = new WebSocketServer({server: server});
```

How do I fix this warning (and effectively the **Identity not verified** problem)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a warning your browser gives. When you take the solution live, buy a certificate and associate with your domain(be exact - wildcard or root certificate) and the warning will go away, and a beatiful lock will come to show the world how safe your site is. :-)

Comment: There's no need to buy a certificate. [Startcom](https://www.startssl.com/) gives you a server certificate for free. They are trusted by most (all?) desktop and mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to purchase a SSL certificate from a certificate authority. A google search will reveal many venders with prices ranging significantly. If you are simply developing and it is not a production website you can find [free certs](https://www.startssl.com/?app=39) or [very cheap certs](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo.aspx). The reason so many certs are expensive ( > 200 USD) is that the venders offer an insurance policy which guarantees the security of the certificate. Although if your cert is compromised and you request an insurance claim from the company, proving that the cert itself was due to fault is incredibly difficult and highly unlikely.

Comment: [Startcom](https://www.startssl.com/) gives you a server certificate for free. They are trusted by most (all?) desktop and mobile browsers. Check out what Peter Gutmann has to say about those hundred or thousand dollar certificates: [PKI Me Harder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#PKI-Me-Harder).